# Appending value to textbox from javascript not working in Android default browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, mobile-website, android-browser

I am trying to implement phone no. masking for Mobile website. And I could not use jquery mask plugin as it was not working properly in devices. Below implementation is working fine in Android Chrome Mobile Browser. But in case of **Android default browser**, when I try to delete all numbers using backspace key, last some(2/3) numbers/digits are not clearing. I guess **this.value += "-";** is not updating some textbox property.
**Phone No. Format is (ex. ###-###-####)**

HTML

```
<input id="phoneNo" type="tel" maxlength="12" placeholder="Phone"/>
```

JavaScript

```
var phoneNo = document.getElementById("phoneNo");
phoneNo.addEventListener("textInput",function(){
if(this.value.toString().length==3 || this.value.toString().length==7) {
   this.value += "-";            
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jQuery on() method as not all browsers support addEventListener which I am guessing is what the problem is.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Darshan please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/51/

In my app also i am using these kind feature. This example

1. Will allow the user to type only integers in field
2. This will automatically add the "-" between numbers like `123-456-7890` format
3. You can delete all the numbers inside the field.

   ```
   $("#fax_field").on("keyup", function(event) {
           var limitField = $(this).val().trim().length;
           var limit = "12"
           this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9_\-\.]/g, '');
           if (event.keyCode != 8) {
             if (limitField == 3) {
               var fax_value = $(this).val().trim().concat('-');
               $("#fax_field").val(fax_value);
             } else if (limitField == 7) {
               var fax_value = $(this).val().trim().concat('-');
               $("#fax_field").val(fax_value);
             }
           }
           if (limitField > limit) {
               $("#fax_field").val($(this).val().trim().substring(0, limit));
           }
       });
   ```

Please try this. Let me know your comments.

Comment: Vinothini, In the above example. When you press keys very fast."-" will not appear.